# Why there are only two panels now? [Info] [Build Settings]

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta

[There are only two panels in my App Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Skju.png)

Before this, I have opened it in Xcode 9 beta2, and now I'm in Xcode 8.3.3. Why there are only two panels left?

Comment: Looks like you selected the project and not the target.

Comment: @rckoenes LOL, Thanks, it really is, I'm new. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected the project and not your build target.

Make sure you have the target list visible.

[image: Project information page]

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, i'm new.